# neo4j-admin import "Multi-line fields are illegal"

Tags: neo4j

I'm getting the following error in Neo4j community 4.1.2 using the neo4-admin import tool.

```
Caused by:ERROR in input
  data source: BufferedCharSeeker[source:/home/ubuntu/workspace/neo4j-community-4.1.2/bin/../import/nodes.csv, position:24455, line:359]
  in field: code:string:6
  for header: [id:ID, labels:LABEL, type:string, flags:string, lineno:string, code:string, childnum:string, funcid:string, classname:string, namespace:string, endlineno:string, name:string, doccomment:string]
  raw field value: 402
  original error: At /home/ubuntu/workspace/neo4j-community-4.1.2/bin/../import/nodes.csv @ position 24455 - Multi-line fields are illegal in this context and so this might suggest that there's a field with a start quote, but a missing end quote. See /home/ubuntu/workspace/neo4j-community-4.1.2/bin/../import/nodes.csv @ position 24455.
```

I checked each single byte with hexedit:

- the line #359
- the char #24455
- the line #358
- the line #360

```
357,AST,string,,34,"/load.php",1,310,,"",,,
358,AST,AST_CALL,,37,,9,310,,"",,,
359,AST,AST_NAME,NAME_NOT_FQ,37,,0,310,,"",,,
360,AST,string,,37,"wp_check_php_mysql_versions",0,310,,"",,,
361,AST,AST_ARG_LIST,,37,,1,310,,"",,,
362,AST,AST_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL,EXEC_REQUIRE,40,,10,310,,"",,,
```

This is the absurd situation:

- no multi-line fields are present
- no special char are present
- no extra 0A byte
- no extra "start quote" without its relative "end quote"

I found some issues on Github but are referred to old versions of Neo4j...what can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the line causing the exception.

The exception cause was correct but the number of the line was totally wrong.

I pointed out it by adding the following flag `--multiline-fields=true` to the  `neo4j-admin import` command.

Comment: Strange. The line number should be reported correctly even without that option.